# php, # in url encoded and mod rewrite avoid decode

Tags: symfony

I have a page with mod rewrite that searches part numbers, these part numbers may have a # in their name, so I have to url encode them to %23 in the url. The problem is that when usign mod rewrite it converts the %23 to # and then I can only retrieve the left part of the part number name.

Example url:
/es/search/ABC%23DEF/

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/search/(.*)/$ index.php?lang=$1&section=search&search=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And if I print the _SEVER and _GET values in the index.php I get:
_SERVER

```
[QUERY_STRING] => lang=es&section=search&search=ABC
[REQUEST_URI] => /es/search/ABC%23DEF/
```

_GET

```
Array
(
    [lang] => es
    [section] => search
    [search] => ABC
)
```

I would need in the search variable the "ABC#DEF" in the url, but this ends in the # symbol, I guess as it identifies it with the anchor in url as mod rewrite has converted it from %23 to #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the question I've found the solution.

The solution is to add the "B" flag in the .htaccess (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)

So the htacces is as follows

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/search/(.*)/$ index.php?lang=$1&section=search&search=$2 [L,QSA,B]
```